# Recycler view seems to return an empty list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have this app that has a recycler view but even though retrofit works (the logger shows the response), the list is not displayed on my app. I added a log statement to my adapter to see what it returned and it seems it's an empty list. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong but any advice would be great.

This is the recycler adapter:

```
package com.app.mortyapp

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.app.mortyapp.databinding.ItemDetailBinding

class RecyclerAdapter(private var characterList: List<Character>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemDetailBinding.inflate(
            layoutInflater,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = characterList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(characterList[position])

    }

    fun setCharacterList(characterList: List<Character>) {
        this.characterList = characterList
        Log.d("CHARACTER LIST SIZE: ", "$characterList")
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(
        private val binding: ItemDetailBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(character: Character) {
            val itemName: TextView = binding.tvName
            val itemGender: TextView = binding.tvGender

            itemName.text = character.name
            itemGender.text = character.gender
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Main activity:

```
package com.app.mortyapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.app.mortyapp.Model.CharacterRepository
import com.app.mortyapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var  binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val characters = mutableListOf<Character>()
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels(
        factoryProducer = {MainViewModelFactory()}
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        progressBar = binding.ProgressBar
        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        setObservers()
        initRecyclerView()
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        with(binding.rvCharacters){
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(characters).apply {
                setCharacterList(characters)
            }
        }

    }

    private fun setObservers(){
        viewModel.characterList.observe(this, Observer {
            when(it.status){
                NetworkStatus.LOADING ->{
                    //show loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                NetworkStatus.SUCCESS -> {
                    //hide loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    //render character list
                    recyclerAdapter.setCharacterList(characters)
                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }
                NetworkStatus.ERROR -> {
                    //show error message
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error loading content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //hide loading state
                    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Remote data source:

```
package com.app.mortyapp

import com.app.mortyapp.Model.CharacterService
import com.app.mortyapp.Model.RetrofitServices
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class CharacterRemoteDataSource {
    fun getCharacterList(networkResponse: NetworkResponse<List<Character>>) {
        val service = RetrofitServices.instance
            .create(CharacterService::class.java)
            .getCharacterList()

        service.enqueue(object : Callback<CharacterListResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<CharacterListResponse>,
                response: Response<CharacterListResponse>
            ) {
                val resource = response.body()?.run {
                    if (results.isNotEmpty())
                        Resource(NetworkStatus.SUCCESS, results)
                    else
                        Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR)
                } ?: run {
                    Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR)
                }
                networkResponse.onResponse(resource)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CharacterListResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                networkResponse.onResponse(Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR, message = t.message))
            }
        })
    }


}

interface NetworkResponse<T> {
    fun onResponse(value: Resource<T>)
}
```

Retrofit's response (I know the serialized name is not necessary there, i'll fix that later):

```
package com.app.mortyapp

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Character (
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("gender") val gender: String
)

data class CharacterListResponse(
    @SerializedName("results") val results: List<Character>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not actually assigning the adapter to the RecyclerView:

> ```
> private fun initRecyclerView() {
>     with(binding.rvCharacters){
>         layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
>         recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(characters).apply {
>             setCharacterList(characters)
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Here you are assigning a LayoutManager to the RecyclerView, but then simply intitializing your Activity's `recyclerAdapter` field. You'll need to add something like this to that `with` block:

```
adapter = recyclerAdapter
```

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean but even if add that, I still don't see anything on my screen